# Is tensor product of simple group representations semisimple?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $S$ and $T$ be simple $kG$-modules for $G$ a finite group. We can form a tensor product $S \otimes_k T$ of these by setting $g\cdot (s \otimes t) = gs \otimes gt$. In this case, is it true that $S\otimes_k T$ is semisimple? If yes, what can we say about its structure?

A thing that I saw in a different post is saying that $U^*\otimes V \cong \textrm{Hom}_k(U,V)$, this could be helpful here. (If you know any reference to this btw, do tell me!)

Comment: Not necessarily - see the second answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57997/tensor-product-of-simple-representations

Comment: For the second question, the natural map $\phi\otimes v\mapsto (u\mapsto \phi(u)v)$ is injective and $G$ stable. When $U, V$ are finite dimensional, computing dimensions shows that it is surjective.